# Переадресация из XML в PHP страницы

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Есть такой сайт "Оружейная" для сервера WoW.

При переходе по любой ссылке в меню

```
_armory.site.ru/search.xml?source=all&type=glyphs&subTp=druid&searchType=items
```

Выдаёт ошибку "404 Not Found"

**Причём есть файлы .htaccess**

```
# UTF8 supportAddDefaultCharset utf8php_value default_charset UTF-8RewriteEngine OnRewriteRule ^(.*).xml $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}# RSS FeedRewriteRule character-feed.atom character-feed-atom.php?%{QUERY_STRING}Options -Indexes
```

или

```
# UTF8 supportAddDefaultCharset utf8#php_value default_charset UTF-8RewriteEngine OnRewriteRule ^(.*).xml $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}RewriteRule character-feed.atom character-feed-atom.php?%{QUERY_STRING}#RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}#RewriteRule ^(.*).htm $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}Options -Indexes
```

**К тому же в apache прописан поддомен вот так:**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>    ServerName site.ru    ServerAlias www.site.ru site.ru    DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/site<Directory "/hdd/backup/www/site">    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews    AllowOverride All    DirectoryIndex index.xml index.php index.html index.htm    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

Пытался переделать под NGINX (у меня установлен вместе с Apache), не переадресовывает... Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: То есть нужно правильно написать реврайт код, с XML на PHP. Помогите плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй в строках с правилами добавить ключи [R,L]

ПримерRewriteRule ^(.*).xml $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R,L]

И в остальных по аналогии.